# Printing using fmt::Display

Tags: printing, rust

I am trying to print an enum (or structure) using fmt::Display. Though the code compiles and gets to the display method, it doesn't print the value.

```
pub enum TestEnum<'a> {
   Foo(&'a str),
   Bar(f32)
}

impl<'b> fmt::Display for TestEnum <'b> {
    fn fmt(&self, f : &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        println!("Got this far");
        match self{
            &TestEnum::Foo(x) => write!(f,"{}",x),
            &TestEnum::Bar(x) => write!(f,"{}",x),
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn test_print() {
        let cell = TestEnum::Str("foo");
        println!("Printing");
        println!("{}",cell); // No output here
    }
}
```

I tried using {:?} and {} but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because Rust test program hides stdout of successful tests. You can disable this behavior passing --nocapture option to test binary or to cargo test command this way:

```
cargo test -- --nocapture
```

PS: your code is broken/incomplete

Answer (score 1):

The test runner seems to divert the standard output; you should consider using `assert!`, `assert_eq!` or other panicky ways to test your assertions rather than printing in tests.

Besides, your code fails to compile due to mismatching names. I got it working as expected from main:

```
use std::fmt;

pub enum TestEnum<'a> {
    Foo(&'a str),
    Bar(f32)
}

impl<'b> fmt::Display for TestEnum <'b> {
    fn fmt(&self, f : &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self {
            &TestEnum::Foo(x) => write!(f, "{}", x),
            &TestEnum::Bar(x) => write!(f, "{}", x),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let cell = TestEnum::Foo("foo");
    println!("Printing");
    println!("{}", cell);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Test output is redirected to a buffer when the test succeeds as to not mangle up with the test "FAILED" or "ok" messages.

---

If you just want to test something while developing your test, you can always add a `panic!()` at the end of your test to make sure it keeps failing and outputting all logging. Or as @AndreaP notes in his answer, you can use `cargo test -- --nocapture` to display the standard output of *all* tests.

---

Usually a test should not write to stdout, but instead write to a buffer and check whether that buffer contains what it should:

```
let cell = TestEnum::Foo("foo");
let mut buf = Vec::new();
let _ = write!(buf, "{}\n", cell);
assert_eq!(&buf, b"foo\n");
```

---

If you truly want to output something, you need to write directly to stdout.

```
let _ = write!(io::stdout(), "{}\n", cell);
```

but this will mix with the test's output:

```
test tests::blub ... foo
ok
```

[PlayPen](http://is.gd/BbRHfW)